# Install extension to all chromium browsers on my computer and make it ENABLED

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

guys! Is there any way that I can install an extension (that is already published in Store) to all of the Chromium browsers that I've got on my Windows 10 PC at once?
Tried to do it, using Registry: added my extension IDs to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions
```

The extensions ARE added but they are DISABLED by default. Maybe there are other ways to achive the same result but make them enabled? Thanks for your support!

P.S. I won't mind if you know ways of loading extensions from CRX files or unpacked ones, if the result will be an enabled extension in all Chromium browsers.

Comment: No; Each installation is independent.  Chrome and Edge both can be managed by a group policy but entirely different group policies.  Why do you have both 32-bit and 64-bit browsers on the same system?

Comment: That's not true. When I've added Extension IDs to this registry key I've got extensions installed into all Profiles of all Chromium browsers.

Comment: When you say Chromium are you talking about Google Chrome and Chromium, or Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge because I know the later is separate.

Comment: For example, Multilogin uses Chromium. Edge? Don't really need that.